# Google Tag Manager - Capture value in class

Tags: javascript, database, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to make a custom JavaScript variable on GTM and need to capture the value in a class.

I've currently got this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("blu-price blu-price-initialised")[0].innerHTML
```

This shows me: `<input type="hidden" value="130.00"><span>£130.00</span>"`

All I want to capture is value= "130.00" or just "£130.00"

This is for tagging on a website which will go into our own database.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
let priceElement = document.getElementsByClassName("blu-price blu-price-initialised")[0]
let price = priceElement.firstElementChild.value
```

Some validation would be required if the input element isn't the first child under each element with className `blu-price blu-price-initialised`.

Comment: <input type="hidden" value="130.00">

Comment: I'll try what you put thank you, that's the first child. I'm not much of a coder as you can tell!

Comment: Thank you so much! Just tried the code it works perfectly!